# Giving money to family on Eid

Tags: money, bidah, eid

Is it permissible to give money to family members to celebrate the day of eid or is it considered bidah?
 We used to give gifts, but we want to avoid the usual, 'my present is better than yours'.

Comment: It depends on your definition of bid'ah. But clearly the vast majority would not say it is a bid'ah.

Comment: It Is not biddah at all ,spending money or giving presents to family on eid days or others are rewardable acts.

Comment: I'd add to the comment of @Kilise those who may say it is bid'ah would say the same about giving gifts on Eid.

Answer (score 1):

Giving gifts is a good deed:

> فإن طبن لكم عن شيء منه نفسا فكلوه هنيئا مريئا
>
> If they give up willingly to you anything of it, then take it in satisfaction and ease.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:4](https://quran.com/4/4?translations=20)</sup>

> البر من ... وآتى المال على حبه ذوي القربى
>
> Righteousness is [in] one who ... gives wealth, in spite of love for it, to relatives
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:177](https://quran.com/2/177?translations=20)</sup>

> كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يقبل الهدية ويثيب عليها
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) used to accept gifts and used to give something in return.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2585)</sup>

> ‏‏ تهادوا تحابوا‏‏
>
> Give gifts and you will love one another
>
> <sup>— [Al-Adab Al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab:594)</sup>

These texts are general and not restricted to the time of the year nor are there any further restrictions on how to implement them. Rather you are free to act on them as and when you wish. If you act on them when it is Eid it remains permissible, just as it is permissible to act on them when it is not Eid.

**Ref:**

> **Question:** We have small children, and the custom in our country is to give them on the day of Eid – whether it is Eid al-Fit or Eid al-Adha – what is known as the “Eidiyyah”, which is a small amount of money, so as to make them happy. Is this Eidiyyah an innovation (bid’ah), or is there nothing wrong with it?
>
> **Answer:**
>
> Praise be to Allah.
>
> There is nothing wrong with that; rather it is a good custom that
> brings joy to the Muslim, whether he is old or young, and it is
> something that is encouraged in Islam.
>
> And Allah is the source of strength. May Allah send blessings and
> peace upon our Prophet Muhammad and his family and companions. End
> quote.
>
> Standing Committee for Academic Research and Issuing Fatwas
>
> Shaykh ‘Abd al-‘Azeez ibn ‘Abdullah ibn Baaz, Shaykh ‘Abd al-‘Azeez
> Aal ash-Shaykh, Shaykh Saalih al-Fawzaan, Shaykh Bakr Abu Zayd.
>
> <sup>— Fataawa al-Lajnah ad-Daa’imah - sourced from [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/125810/giving-children-eid-money-on-the-two-eids)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

yes it is permissable as it is Eid.

you might be talking about kids in this case thinking there presents are better then the other maybe try to talk to them and try to get them out of that state